# Json attribute not showing in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, string, attribute

I have a Json string and something does not make any sense to me. Here is the problem:

I have a Json string with the following attributes in it:

```
[{"MiddleName":"der","LastName":"Emmerzaal"},{"LinkName":"en"},{"MiddleName":"van der","LastName":"Lukaart"}]
```

In my HTML code it will be printed like this:

```
{{#JsonVarforwardmailnames}}{{MiddleName}}&nbsp;{{LastName}}&nbsp;{{LinkName}}&nbsp;{{/JsonVarforwardmailnames}}
```

Now the MiddleName and the LastName are printed correctly but the LinkName isn't showing. I can't figure out why not. I have set my VAR's and set up the following dataobject:

```
{{.dataobject JsonVarforwardmailnames type=variable source=@forwardmailnames maxrows=20}} 
{{.data}} 
{"target":"@forwardmailnames"}
{{/data}} 
{{/dataobject}
```

Hopefully someone will see the problem. THanks in advanced.

Martijn

Comment: Is this question related to Salesforce Marketing Cloud? Tagging as such can help.

Comment: Yes sorry. I just edited.

Comment: Link name appears to be in a separate object than your middle/lastnames.  This is likely why it is appearing blank as the name/key value does not exist in the first object that you are viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's endent your GTL code so It becomes more easy to read

```or-tag-here
{{#JsonVarforwardmailnames}}
  {{MiddleName}}
  {{LastName}}
  {{LinkName}}
{{/JsonVarforwardmailnames}}
```

As you can see, It is expecting an object with three parameters : `MiddleName`, `LastName` and `LinkName`

The Json Object should look like this :

```or-tag-here
  {
    "MiddleName": "der",
    "LastName": "Emmerzaal",
    "LinkName": "en"
  }
```

Comment: Ahhhh so logical. I totaly didn;'t see that. Thanks a lot!